# Vertical alignment of text within a <div>

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a webpage and learning how to use stylesheets.

I have 3 side by side "div" boxes, each with an image and text underneath the image.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
.prod_img_box {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="prod_img_box">
  <img src="direct.png" alt="Storage Vessels" class="prod_img" border=2/>
  <h3 class="white_font">Storage Vessels</h3>
</div>
<div class="prod_img_box">
  <img src="tran_imm.png" alt="Immersion Heaters" class="prod_img" border=2/>
  <h3 class="white_font">Immersion Heaters</h3>
</div>
<div class="prod_img_box">
  <img src="at_chrome.png" alt="Towel Rail Heating Elements" class="prod_img " border=2/>
  <h3 class="white_font">Towel Rail Heaters</h3>
</div>
```

This gives me something like the following:

[image]

which is **almost** what I want - but the text underneath each image is currently vertically centered (as it should be as it is inside the "prod_img_box" - but I want the text to be all in a horizontal line at the bottom.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this. Should it be something like:

```
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="text">Storage Vessels</div>
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="text">Immersion Heaters</div>
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="text">Towel Rail Elements</div>
```

The webpage can be [found here](http://commercialwaterheating.com/testing/) also.

Comment: This fundamental question about how to use CSS has a multitude of answers and tutorials all over the internet and here on SO using the search function at the top of the screen.

Comment: have you considered using a grid and let the biggest image set the height so you can still center align the smaller images and print the text beneath each image on a separate row?

if you always know how many images that will be displayed horizontally the suggested idea could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
<div class="text">Storage Vessels</div>
```

and then set height for image class to set the text always stay at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Check border** in this class It should be `2px solid black;` or `2px solid #000;`

```
.prod_img_box {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

And Remove **border=2** from every image tag if not required

**Note:** If you are using **# tag** then you need to set color by color code i.e. `#000` or if you are using direct color name then you don't need to put **# tag**

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default height to the div so that however the image is , it will display all the divs to be same and thus same level of texts.

Answer (score -1):

The `Div` element is most commonly used to keep a group of content together. If you would like to keep the code together, the best way of moving the text is simply manipulating the `padding` and `margin` properties in the `CSS` file.

Comment: This does not answer the question.